# Como posso dividir as parcelas, adicionando apenas valores exatos para cada parcela, sendo que uma parcela vai ficar com um valor a mais?

Tags: java, html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Exemplo: A divisão de 100(valor de entrada) por 3(quantidade de parcelas) é igual a 33.33, sendo que  3 * 33.33 = 99,99. 
Sendo que o certo é ficar uma parcela com o valor 33.34.

**Código Java**

```
public void parcelar() {
    listaParcela = new ArrayList<>();
    //if (compra.getQtdparcelas() == null) {
    //   if (compra.getQtdparcelas() > 1) {
    Double totalP = compra.getValortotalentrada() / 
    compra.getQtdparcelas().doubleValue();
    DateTime data = new DateTime(pagar.getVencimento());
    for (int i = 1; i <= compra.getQtdparcelas(); i++) {
        Cpagar par = new Cpagar();
        par.setVencimento(data.toDate());
        par.setValor(totalP);
        par.setFormaPagamentoId(pagar.getFormaPagamentoId());
        par.setObs(campoconsulta);
        par.setContas(compra);
        compra.getContasList().add(par);
        listaParcela.add(par);
        data = data.plusMonths(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Leia mais sobre aritmética de pontos flutuantes, pode começar com essa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/64969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
double diferenca = compra.getValortotalentrada() - (totalP * compra.getQtdparcelas().doubleValue());
```

Vamos supor que o valor é 100 então o totalLP seria 33.33 como no seu exemplo.

A lógica é a seguinte:

```
diferenca = 100  - (33.33 * 3)
diferenca = 100  - (99.99)
direfenta = 0.01
```

Ao entrar no loop ele adiciona esta diferença na primeira parcela:

```
par.setValor(totalP + diferenca);
```

E no final para não adicionar nas outras atribuo 0 em diferença:

```
diferenca = 0;
```

Segue o exemplo:

```
public void parcelar() {
    listaParcela = new ArrayList<>();
    //if (compra.getQtdparcelas() == null) {
    //   if (compra.getQtdparcelas() > 1) {
    Double totalP = compra.getValortotalentrada() / 
    compra.getQtdparcelas().doubleValue();
    DateTime data = new DateTime(pagar.getVencimento());
    double diferenca = compra.getValortotalentrada() - (totalP * compra.getQtdparcelas().doubleValue());
    for (int i = 1; i <= compra.getQtdparcelas(); i++) {
        Cpagar par = new Cpagar();
        par.setVencimento(data.toDate());
        par.setValor(totalP + diferenca);
        par.setFormaPagamentoId(pagar.getFormaPagamentoId());
        par.setObs(campoconsulta);
        par.setContas(compra);
        compra.getContasList().add(par);
        listaParcela.add(par);
        data = data.plusMonths(1);
        diferenca = 0;
    }
}
```